# ¿Como enviar datos a una api por php?

Tags: php, api, post

Estoy usando la API de Billage, es un codigo sencillo para poder crear una empresa, antes este codigo funcionaba pero ha dejado de funcionar, creo que es su API el problema pero dejo el codigo a ver si alguien encuentra algo mal en el codigo php. (Siempre da error)
Esta es la web de la api:https://app.getbillage.com/api/documentation.html#/Accounts/account_create

````
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

$authToken = 'mi_api';

$postData = array(
    "client" => true,
    "alias" => 'nombre_empersa',
    "business_name" => 'nombre_comercial_empresa'
);

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Authorization: ".$authToken,
        'content' => json_encode($postData)
    )
));

$response = file_get_contents('https://app.getbillage.com/api/v2/accounts', FALSE, $context);
if($response === FALSE){
    die('Error');
}

$responseData = json_decode($response, TRUE);
var_dump($responseData);```
````

Comment: Por mucho que repitas la pregunta no vas a obtener mejores respuestas, es más, puedes ser penalizado por ello.  En cuanto a tu pregunta, resulta dificil ayudar sin un token correcto, pues da error de usuario no autorizado en mis pruebas, y no llego a ver el porque te pasa eso.  Prueba de lanzar el php desde terminal y ver si alli se muestran mejor los errores.

Comment: ya te conteste en el otro post, tenia prisa